# Trying to replace integer in text file with a user inputted integer [C++]

Tags: c++, file, replace, cin

```
ifstream file;
file.open("Data.txt");

string name;
string names[5];
string weight;
string weights[5];
int skip = 3;
int count = 0;
int count2 = 0;
int index[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int user;

while (file >> names[count])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 names
{
    for (int i = 0; i < skip; i++)
        file >> name; //For each time i is less that 3, then output the names read from the file to the console
    count++;
}

file.close();
file.open("Data.txt");

file.ignore(5);

while (file >> weights[count2])  //While the file goes through the txt file and collects 5 names
{
    for (int i = 0; i < skip; i++)
        file >> weight; //For each time i is less that 3, then output the names read from the file to the console
    count2++;

}

for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    cout << index[j] << ". " << "Name: " << names[j] << ", " << "Current Weight(KG): " << weights[j] << '\n'; //Output all of the files collected and stored in the names array
}

file.close();

int choice;
int newWeight;

cout << "Which index would you like to change?" << endl;
cin >> choice;

switch (choice) {
case 1:
    cout << "You have chosen index " << choice << " which is " << names[choice - 1] << " who weighs " << weights[choice - 1] << "KG" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the user's new weight" << endl;
    cin >> newWeight;
    weights[choice] = newWeight;
    file.open("Data.txt");

    cout << "Changed" << endl;
    file.close();
    break;
}
```

So i have a text file which stores details about 5 users: Name, weight, previous weights and height. Im trying to update a users weight in the file by getting an input from a user. So if the user's weight in the txt file was 90, and the user inputted 95, then i want to change the weight in the file from 90 to 95

The program already reads in the weight and the user's name so i just need to know how to replace the weight in the text file.

[Text file with user data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RfMS.png)

Comment: Can you show the actual work you've already done to attempt to actually read the file; and then explain how exactly it doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results. You have to show your work first, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. Noone on stackoverflow.com will write a bunch of new code in response to this type of a question. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: I've added the full function that reads the user's name and weight from the file

Comment: Ok, now explain what is your specific question, what is the specific problem, with the shown code, that you're asking about.

Comment: So the program reads the user's name and weight from the txt file. It then asks the user which user's weight they would like to change. So for example if they chose user 1, then the program would ask them what they would like to change user 1's weight to. The user then enters the new weight. So i want the new weight to replace the user's old weight in the file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot overwrite a specific line in a file on disk. You will have to read in the entire file and store it in memory, make the adjustment to the value based on the user input, and then recreate the file and write the result to disk which overwrites the previous file.

Comment: You can overwrite a specific line, but it is so much harder, orders of magnitude harder, than rewriting the file that it's almost always not worth doing.

Comment: You don't have to store the entire file in the memory, you can read an arbitrary amount of bytes from the file and write it to some other file immediately.